Create alarm in react-native
I'm very new in react-native, i come from react and to get started in this i started with an alarm app, my problem is that there is little information or is very old and i have not found a way to make a simple alarm.
I have tried notifee (but it fails with sound and vibration), react-native-push-notification (same as notifee), i have tried some libraries like react-native-alarm-manager but their documentation is poor and their implementation doesn't work for me for many compatibilities reasons (otherwise i think no is the better option)
I have searched for android alarm manager but i have no knowledge of JAVA of kotlin, so, i have not been able to make native modules.
Could someone help me to solve this or unless give me some tip to create it?
